# How to create related objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So I have four models

```
class User
  has_many :user_rows
end

class Assignment
  has_many :rows
end

class Row
  belongs_to :assignment
  has_many :user_rows
end

class UserRow
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :row
end
```

On the `assignment` show view I want to loop through the `rows` and for each `row` have a `user_row` to capture `user` input.

My question is how to intialize the user rows.  Would it be best to do this?

```
class AssignmentController
  def show
    @assignment = Assignment.include(:rows).find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Then in the view just use `first_or_create`

```
<%= @assignment.rows.each do |row| %>
  <%= row.data %>
  <%= form_for UserRow.where(row_id: row.id, user_id: current_user.id).first_or_create, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= form_fields %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

As you can see the objects need to be iterated over in the view.

Which I don't like particularly because it's initializing an object in the view.  Or is it best to create all the `user_rows` for each `row` when a user signs up to the site and if a new row is created create a `user_row` for all users?

Or is there a better solution I've missed?

Comment: `UserRow.where(row_id: row.id, user_id: current_user.id)` can be `row.user_rows`

Comment: Thanks.  On my actual main problem though something like [this](http://brandonhilkert.com/blog/refactoring-logic-from-a-rails-view/) might be useful, looks like a good way of starting to do what I want

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` might help you. You might check these documents.

[fields_for (ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/fields_for)

[accepts_nested_attributes_for (ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes::ClassMethods) - APIdock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)

Comment: I'd still need to initialize the build somewhere wouldn't I?